# Remotely access developer desktop located at home

Tags: linux, remote-access, desktop-client, ssh, virtual-machine

**I'm looking for a way to remotely use desktop computer located at home from a laptop from any location over Internet.**

**The Setup:**

- Windows with VirtualBox running several virtual machines (Linux for now).

**Requirements:**

- No need to remotely connect to Windows.
- There has to be a way to SSH into all those virtual hosts.
- One of hosts is Ubuntu which is my developer desktop, I need visual remote desktop connection to it.
- Setup should work with both Windows and Mac laptops.

**Could you tell me which technologies and tools to use?**

- *How to obtain SSH-able domain name for my desktop.*
- *What are tradeoffs when using each of them?*
- *Which part of the goal is solved by each of those tools?*

Comment: Assuming you have the virtual machines setup to be able to access/be access from the internet * *think* that you should be able to use any of the suggestions from [this Q](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/remote-desktop-software-for-linux) or [this one](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/remote-desktop-software-from-linux-to-windows). Do none of those options work for you?

Comment: Thanks for links, for me bigger challange is actually to get ip or hostname of desktop.
Any ideas about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know TeamViewer 8 (even the free version) can do this. I use it to connect to my home machine when I'm out and also to connect from my home machine to romote ones. You just need to remember the password that is shown on the machine you want to connect to. Once connected, the machine you are using simply 'becomes' the remote machine. Dead easy to transfer files as well. I even use it to connect my laptop to my desktop machine via the Internet so I can program when I'm too lazy to get out of bed in the morning!